# preventDefault() until confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Email reset form, displays a confirm box with `input: email` Asks the user to confirm email. (spelling/etc) If user clicks **ok** form should submit normally. If user clicks **cancel** allow them to change email.

```
  $(function(){
    $('form').on('submit',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      var email = $('#user_email').val();
      if(email.length == 0){
        alert('Please enter your email address.');
      } else {
        confirm('Are you sure you want to reset the password for: '+ email);
        // if confirm [ok] submit the form!!!!
      } 
    });
  });
```

Side question: Can I pass in the email input value to `confirm` attribute in rails input helper? (that would allow me to avoid having to write the additional `js`)

e.g.

```
  <%= button_tag type: 'submit', id: "email-confirm", confirm: "Are you sure you want to reset the password for: #{email-input-value}" do %>
    Send me reset password instructions
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Remove the `event.preventDefault()`, and put `return false` inside the `if` statement (after the `alert`), and change the `confirm` line to `return confirm('...`. This should prevent the form from submitting when the email isn't filled in or when they cancel the `confirm`

Comment: Thanks dude! That's exactly what I needed. Is that Professor Feeny? lol =)

Comment: No, it's my teacher from elementary school ;-)

Comment: Your site is very nice. Who is your designer? What framework does it run on?

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could say I had a hand in the design/development, but I didn't. And the designers are just employees in the company (all done in-house). It's made with Wordpress, but Wordpress is really only used for the CMS. They do **a lot** of custom JavaScript and CSS (it's quite responsive), but that's about as much as I know

Comment: Sweet, well thanks for the assist. If you want the rep post as answer so that I can accept. l8 =)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the form from submitting and can't be undone. You can make use of `return`ing from this handler instead, where returning `false` prevents the default behavior (same as `e.preventDefault()`) **and** stops the event from propagating (same as `e.stopPropagation()`). Since `confirm` returns a boolean based on what button the user clicked, you can just `return` that value. In addition, you want to prevent the submit when the email isn't filled in (right after the `alert`), so put a `return false;` there. Here's an example:

```
$(function(){
  $('form').on('submit',function(e){
    var email = $('#user_email').val();
    if(email.length == 0){
      alert('Please enter your email address.');
      return false;
    } else {
      return confirm('Are you sure you want to reset the password for: '+ email);
    } 
  });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/tyaw1az1/

Answer (score 0):

Given that JQuery is almost obsolete at this point, here is the vanilla javascript solution:

```js
let form = document.getElementById('<form id here>')

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    return (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to reset your password?'))? true : e.preventDefault()
})
```

Now the form won't submit till the confirm dialogue pops up and the user clicks OK.